# How to use mongodb with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to make authentication using mongodb. I found this code snippet:

```
var express     = require('express');
var MongoStore  = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var app         = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser()); // required to handle session cookies!
app.use(express.session({
  secret  : 'YOUR_SESSION_SECRET',
  cookie  : {
    maxAge  : 10000              // expire the session(-cookie) after 10 seconds
  },
  store   : new MongoStore({
    db: 'sessionstore'
    // see https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#options for more options
  })
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var previous      = req.session.value || 0;
  req.session.value = previous + 1;
  res.send('<h1>Previous value: ' + previous + '</h1>');
});

app.listen(3012);
```

But when i start application i got error:

```
E:\Dev\mongoTest>node index.js
E:\Dev\mongoTest\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:99
      throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled
with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/sen
chalabs/connect#middleware.');
  ^

Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must
 be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middl
eware.
at Function.get (E:\Dev\mongoTest\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:99:13)

at connectMongo (E:\Dev\mongoTest\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:49
:43)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Dev\mongoTest\index.js:2:43)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Im new with node.js, so what i can forgot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
```